# AWK : replacing number by number of repetitions

Tags: regex, awk, numbers, repeat, backreference

I have an awk question, let's say I have this:

```
up2left3right
```

I want to use awk to change it to this:

```
up
up
left
left
left
right
```

Any ideas on how this is possible?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a `gnu awk` version (due to `RS` and `RT`)

```
echo "up2left3right" | awk  '{for (i=1;i<=(RT?RT:1);i++)  if (NF) print $0}' RS="[0-9]"
up
up
left
left
left
right
```

It changes the Record Separator to a number.
Then the `RT` stores the `RS` used and we uses a loop to repeat the data.

---

Updated version that now works with number larger than `9` (multiple digits)
Also added `\n` in `RS` to work correctly at end of line and if multiple line

```
awk '{i=RT=="\n"?1:RT;while(i--) if (NF) print $0}' RS="[0-9]+|\n" file
```

```
echo -e "up3left12right\ntest4more" | awk '{i=RT=="\n"?1:RT;while(i--) if (NF) print $0}' RS="[0-9]+|\n"
up
up
up
left
left
left
left
left
left
left
left
left
left
left
left
right
test
test
test
test
more
```

Comment: @Jotne, +1. nice answer. Today I learned a new variable `RT`.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. I don't have GNU awk on my OSX Mac. Does this handle "up12left22" and double-digit fields? And do such fiedls occur in the OP's stream?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Good point, I thought `RS="[0-9]+"` would fix it, but it doesn't. Anyways, have you toyed with the idea of having [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) installed on your mac. It's really cool!

Comment: @jaypal Another option would be to use perl.  It wouldn't suffer from the limitation.

Comment: @user2849420 Welcome to StackOverflow. Here you can thank by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer as a token of your appreciation.

Comment: @jaypal Its some sad that `FS` does not have the `FT` siblings.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Added new version that supports double-digit :)

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to use `perl`:

```
$ echo up2left3right | perl -pe 's/([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)/"$1\n" x $2/gse;'
up
up
left
left
left
right
```

Now with *counts* greater than 10:

```
$ echo up2down10left2right | perl -pe 's/([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)/"$1\n" x $2/gse;'
up
up
down
down
down
down
down
down
down
down
down
down
left
left
right
```

Comment: @jaypal I was some negative before to people using loops, if other solution was available, but learned from other and by testing, that an `awk` with loop, may even be faster than an `awk` with out.  So loop does not automatically equal to slow solution.

Comment: @Jotne True, I was just saying in context of cleaner code that `perl` offered. Not often you'll see that happening. `;)`

Comment: +1 for the very good solution. Could you explain the behaviour for us newbies in perl? I can kind of "play" with your solution, but cannot really understand it.

Comment: @fedorqui `x` is the [multiplication operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators). `e` evaluates the right side as an expression.  The idea is to match string and numbers and use the numbers to _multiply_ the string!

Answer (score 2):

Here is possible way with regular `awk`:

```
$ echo "up2left3right1wrong2boo" | 
awk '{x=gsub(/[0-9]+/," & ");for(i=1;i<=x*2;i+=2){while($(i+1)--)print $i};if(i)print $i}'
up
up
left
left
left
right
wrong
wrong
boo
```

We basically create a space before and after a number and loop through each element. Once we encounter a word number pair, we use `while loop` to continue printing the word until number is exhausted. If word exists stand alone then testing with `if` loop we print it.

Though it will break where word is missing number and is followed by words with numbers. For following case it will consider `rightwrong` as one word:

```
up2left3rightwrong2
```

Comment: `rightwrong` this will break any solution. A computer is a computer and does what its told.  You can off course add an dictionary and make a cross match to see if you find readable words :)

Comment: @Jotne Yeah, dunno why I chose to give that disclaimer. It probably prevented some up-votes for sure! `:)`.

Comment: Another small thought.  I would have looked at what created this stupid input and then fixed that, so every word was on separate line with number to repeat behind.  But it was some interesting to solve this, since it was some I not remember to seen here before :)

Comment: @Jotne Interesting for sure. Got to know the usefulness and limitations of `RT` built in

Comment: If you have an regex as `RS` the `RT` will then contain the actual data used for that.  Here is an example.  Remove the tags and print the data: `echo "<tag>something</tag><tag>more data</tag>" | awk 'RT=="</tag>"' RS='</?tag>'`